# functions as template arguments

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

I have a TaskWrapper:

```
template <typename T, T (*F)(T)>
struct TaskWrapper {
  static inline T run(T clock) {
    return F(clock);
  }
};
```

to use it I have to specify the T template argument:

```
uint16_t task1(uint16_t clock) { return clock + 1; }
typedef tasks::TaskWrapper<uint16_t, task1> Task;
```

I would like to simply write:

```
typedef tasks::TaskWrapper<task1> Task;
```

and let the compiler figure out that the return and argument type is uint16_t.

Notes:

The TaskWrapper is obviously simplified and in reality has a few other arguments, which are passed during the typedef.

The wrapped functions can only be:

```
uint8_t task(uint8_t clock);
uint16_t task(uint16_t clock); // or
uint32_t task(uint32_t clock);
```

The TaskWrapper is passed as template argument to another class, which will at some point call Task::run(...);

C++11 would be fine.

Comment: What about `template<typename T> using Task = tasks::TaskWrapper<T, task1>;` and then use it as `Task<uint8_t>`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only since C++17's [template <auto>](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0127r2.html) feature:

```
template <auto F>
struct TaskWrapper {
  template <typename T>
  static inline auto run(T clock) {
    return F(clock);
  }
};

uint16_t task1(uint16_t clock) { return clock + 1; }
typedef TaskWrapper<&task1> Task; // ok
```

Comment: Oh I like!  Would have been very useful in [this snippet I just wrote](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40389000/103167)

Answer (score 2):

You can move the template argument to the site of invocation, but this will make it correspond to the argument passed for the deduction, eg:

```
template <typename F, F functor>
struct TaskWrapper {
  template<typename T>
  static inline T run(T clock) {
    return functor(clock);
  }
};

uint16_t task1(uint16_t clock) { return clock + 1; }
typedef TaskWrapper<decltype(task1), task1> Task;

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
  Task task;
  Task::run(10);
  return 0;
}
```

So that it will generate a `static inline int run(int clock)`, which is not the same argument type of the initial function but could be enough for your purpose.

Answer (score 2):

Templates are easy when using types and not values as arguments. Can you convert your functions to functors? If yes, then a possible solution were:

```
template<class F>
struct TaskWrapper {
  using T = decltype(F::operator());
  static inline T run(T clock) {
    return F(clock);
  }
};

struct task1_t {
  uint16_t operator()(uint16_t clock) {
    return clock + 1;
  }
};

using Task = TaskWrapper<task1_t>;
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's possible what do you exactly ask: if you want to pass the functions as template **value**, without express the type, you have to know the type before; but the type of the function is what do you want to deduce.

If you accept to pass the **type** of the function, as follows

```
template <typename>
struct taskWrapper;

template <typename T>
struct taskWrapper<std::function<T(T)>>
 {
   static inline T run (std::function<T(T)> const & F, T clock)
    { return F(clock); };
 };
```

you can define define your `typedef`s

```
typedef taskWrapper<std::function<decltype(task8)>>  tsk8;
typedef taskWrapper<std::function<decltype(task16)>> tsk16;
typedef taskWrapper<std::function<decltype(task32)>> tsk32;
```

but you can see that `taskWrapper<std::function<decltype(task8)>>` know only the **type** of `task8()`, not the `task8()` function itself; so you have to pass the function to `run()`.

The following is a working example.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

template <typename>
struct taskWrapper;

template <typename T>
struct taskWrapper<std::function<T(T)>>
 {
   static inline T run (std::function<T(T)> const & F, T clock)
    { return F(clock); };
 };

uint8_t task8 (uint8_t clock)
 { return ++clock; }

uint16_t task16 (uint16_t clock)
 { return ++clock; }

uint32_t task32 (uint32_t clock)
 { return ++clock; }

typedef taskWrapper<std::function<decltype(task8)>>  tsk8;
typedef taskWrapper<std::function<decltype(task16)>> tsk16;
typedef taskWrapper<std::function<decltype(task32)>> tsk32;

int main ()
 {
   tsk8   t8;
   tsk16  t16;
   tsk32  t32;

   std::cout << t8.run(task8,   uint8_t(64)) << std::endl;  // print A
   std::cout << t16.run(task16, uint16_t(65)) << std::endl; // print 66
   std::cout << t32.run(task32, uint32_t(66)) << std::endl; // print 67
 }
```

Hope this helps.