# Comparer that takes the wanted attribute

Tags: c++

In order to use a standard function like `std::sort` on some standard container `Container<T>`

```
struct T{
    int x,y;
};
```

based on the `y` value, you need to write something like (for example):

```
std::vector<T> v;
//fill v
std::sort(v.begin(),v.end(),[](const auto& l,const auto& r){
    return l.y<r.y;
});
```

The comparer that was written as lambda function is used too much and re-written again and again during the code for various classes and attributes.

Considering the case where `y`'s type is comparable (either like `int` or there is an overload for the `< operator`), is there any way to achieve something like:

```
std::sort(v.begin(),v.end(),imaginary::less(T::y)); // Imaginary code
```

Is it possible in C++ to write such a function like `less`? or anything similar?

I am asking because I remember something like that in some managed language (I am not sure maybe C# or Java). However, I am not sure even about this information if it is true or not.

Comment: Would you be happy with code that allows you to say `member_less<T, &T::y>()` ?

Comment: @Nathan: But that doesn't allow you to select which member to sort by, at the call to `std::sort`.

Comment: @BenVoigt Ah.  I did not see that was what the OP was trying to do.  silly me.

Comment: @BenVoigt Yup I would

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
template<typename T, typename MT>
struct memberwise_less
{
    MT T::* const mptr;
    auto operator()(const T& left, const T& right) const
    { return (left.*mptr) < (right.*mptr); }
};

template<typename T, typename MT>
memberwise_less<T, MT> member_less(MT T::*mptr)
{
    return { mptr };
}
```

and then you can do

```
std::sort(v.begin(), v.end(), member_less(&T::y));
```

Comment: This is not compile-tested... if you share a test case that creates the vector, prints the results, etc., I'll be happy to add this to the test.